# How to mark a question as duplicate

Tags: discussion, duplicates

how to make or mark a question duplicate of other question ??? I came across many of such question can anybody tell me how to mark question a duplicate (does it require rep??)...

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges This and some of your other questions on meta (to me) seem rather basic and are FAQ related. I would suggest to browse the help section to improve your knowledge about how stack-sites work ;-) Or join us in the chat :D

Comment: @Rinzwind - I don't see any thing related to marking a question as duplicate...

Comment: You're looking for  http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/flag-posts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [flag](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) after at least 15 reputation on question or answer as following:

---

[image: screen1]

---

At main list:

[image: screen2]

---

Under "It should be closed for another reason":

[image: screen3]

---

In addition after 3k reputation option as [**close question**](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/close-questions).